# Database design: two rows or more in a table how to connect them together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am making a banking system. When you make a transaction from one account to another i will make to rows/records in my Transaction table. But i need to connect them together, so when i look the transaction up i can see both sides. My question is should i make another table which records this or should i add a column which holds a TransactionHeadID of some kind? Or is there a third and better option?

Answer (score 0):

You can make one table which holds transaction details, senderId and receiverId.
senderId and receieverId will be foreign keys to User table.

Comment: That will be okay for now. But i plan on make it possible to whitdraw 100 $ and then insert them to 5 accounts with 20$ each. Then this don´t work.

Comment: then you will have one row for withdrawing and 5 for deposit.

Comment: Im considering a transaction as an unique and whole operation.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to add fields "from" and "to" to your Transaction table. Then, if for example you move 100$ from A to 40$ in B and 60$ in C, your table would look like this:

```
 Account | Value | From | To
---------+-------+------+------
 A       | -40   | NULL | B
 A       | -60   | NULL | C
 B       |  40   | A    | NULL
 C       |  60   | A    | NULL
```

However, I think it would be better if you used two tables: a Transaction table containing truly the transaction info indedpendent of from and to accounts, like store,date etc and some TransactionID, and another table called for example TransactionBalanceEvent which would have a TransactionID foreign key, Account number, balance. Then you would have:

Transaction Table

```
TranID | Date
-------+----------
1      | some_date
```

TransactionBalanceEvent Table

```
TranID|Account|Balance
------+-------+-------
1     |      A|   -100
1     |      B|     40
1     |      C|     60
```